# Angular Jasmine: TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic3, angular5

I am working on a project of Angular 5 with Ionic 3. I am using Jasmine for unit testing. I have integrated Angular-Cli for project. My setup was working till yesterday but today it is not working. On executing `test` command, it is showing following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null
>           at 
>           at UserContext. node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:106:1)
>           at 
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   node_modules/zone.js/dist /zone.js:421:1)
>           at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:1)
>           at drainMicroTaskQueue node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:1)
>           at

Any idea why it is happening ?

Comment: what is ```UserContext``` ?

Comment: I have not used any UserContext. I guess it might be coming from Jasmine library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from `zone.js` (see this [post](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1496) and the stack trace is the error above). Upgrading your `zone.js` and it will be fixed.